# Test SessionsConstroller Devise + RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I have this custom create method on SessionsController:

```
def create
    puts "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
    if view_only?
        login_visualizacao
        return
    end
    puts "1111111111111111"

   super
    puts "2222222222222222"
    set_token current_usuario, nil unless !current_usuario
end
```

And trying to test this using RSpec, like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Usuarios::SessionsController do# do, :type => :controller do
    describe 'Realizar login' do
        let(:codigo) { '1020' }
        let(:senha) { '12345' }

        context 'quando o login via API é feito corretamente' do
            # let(:user) { Usuario.new(codigo: codigo, password: senha) }
            let(:user) { mock_model(Usuario, codigo: codigo, password: senha) }

            before do
                setup_controller_for_warden
                @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:usuario]
                allow(user).to receive(:authenticatable_salt)
                allow(subject).to receive(:super)
                sign_in(user)
                # allow(subject).to receive(:current_usuario).and_return(user)
                allow(subject).to receive(:set_token)                   
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I put these lines of code in my spec_helper:

```
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :request
```

The problem is that my RSpec test isn't printing "2222222222", I think the super code isn't being executed successfully, the user isn't being logged and therefore the current_usuario is nil. I don't know whatelse is missing, can anybody help me? How can I mock the call to super method?

Comment: When you call `super`, i think it is successfully executing `create` action of super class and rendering/redirecting to some path. So, it is not able to continue execution to next lines in your `create` action. Try stubbing `super` as `allow(controller).to receive(:stub){}`.

Comment: It didn't work.. :(